# Convert boost::shared_ptr to actual class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-smart-ptr

How would someone do that?
for example:

```
Client* client = it->second;
```

where it->second is a boost::shared_ptr to Client
error:

```
cannot convert `const ClientPtr' to `Client*' in initialization
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

boost::shared_ptr has a .get() method to retrieve the raw pointer.

Documentation here about when and why not to use it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `get` method on the `boost::shared_ptr` to retrieve the pointer, but be **very** careful in what you do : extracting a naked pointer from a reference counted shared pointer can be dangerous (deletion will be triggered if the reference count reaches zero, thus invalidating your raw pointer).

Answer (score 2):

`boost:shared_ptr` overloads `operator*`:

```
boost::shared_ptr< T > t_ptr(new T());
*t_ptr; // this expression is a T object
```

To get a pointer to `t` you can either use `get` function or take `*t_ptr` address:

```
&*t_ptr; // this expression is a T*
```

The first method (using `get`) is probably better, and has less overhead, but it only works with `shared_ptr`s (or pointers with a compatible API), not with other kind of pointers.

Comment: Technically (although quite unlikely), `operator&()` could be overloaded, so I'd stick with `.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Not dangerous but c-ctor involved.

```
Client client( *(it->second.get()) );
```